# Convert audio-only flv to aac: ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, aac

I can't convert a simple audio-only .flv to AAC format. The audio stream is obviously there, and I can hear it on manual playback. Are there different parameters I need to accomplish this?

```
ffmpeg -i test.flv test.aac
[flv @ 0x23b3260]Could not find codec parameters (Video: 0x0000)
Input #0, flv, from 'test.flv':
  Duration: 00:00:12.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: 0x0000, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: nellymoser, 8000 Hz, mono, s16
Output #0, adts, to 'test.aac':
    Stream #0.0: Audio: 0x0000, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.0
Unsupported codec for output stream #0.0
```

Comment: Looks like it wants to encode the *video* stream in AAC, which obviously has to fail. Strange - it shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i test.flv  -acodec libfaac  test.aac
```

You can use the following to set bitrate, sample rate, and channels, respectively:

```
-ab 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2
```

Also, you may have to tell ffmpeg what steam you want to encode, by doing:

```
ffmpeg -i test.flv -map 0:1 -acodec libfaac  test.aac
```

Which corespondes to

```
Stream #0.1: Audio: nellymoser, 8000 Hz, mono, s16
```

Comment: Thanks. Also I used the -vn option helped because it ignored the video stream:
`ffmpeg -i test.flv -vn -acodec copy test.aac`

Comment: Jasie, I can confirm these settings work for me and those are also the same used by `get-iplayer` to convert audio-only flvs.

Comment: "-f" is not needed in the command of "ffmpeg -i test.flv  -acodec libfaac  test.aac" ?

Comment: What about the other way around? aac to flv?